# unable to login user account in domain controller server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I  have installed server 2008 in my pc and configured the DC then I created a user  and  accounts. I am trying to login to the DC using user account nut but I am unable to loging to DC.

Answer (score 1):

By default a user will not be able to login to the console of a domain controller.  For security reasons you generally do not what users to have physical access to a DC or they can do evil things.

If you really think this is necessary follow the procedure described here [To permit users to log on locally to a domain controller](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785165(WS.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What Zoredache said, except, if that account is for a Domain Admin, simply add them to the correct security group and they should be able to logon.

Comment: Right, this works too.

Comment: If the account is a domain admin, they're already in the correct group. The Domain Admins group is a member of the domain builtin group Administrators, which is granted the "allow logon locally" user right.

Comment: He didn't specify.. but you are 100% correct.

Comment: Right, I was responding to your answer. I may have misunderstood what you meant. I thought you were saying that if the account is a Domain Admin (member of the domain admins group) that the OP should then add the user to the correct group and my comment was that any member of the Domain Admins group is by virtue of nested membership also a member of the domain builtin group Administrators, which has the allow logon locally user right on domain controllers.

Comment: By "Correct security group" I was referring to Domain Admin, apologies if that wasn't clear.